# How to test EF Models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, testing

I am trying to figure out how to write Entity Framework Code First code via TDD. I am finding it hard since it I do not have a test database as I have had in the past with Ruby On Rails. Probably easier to explain with an example:

Currently I have:

```
public interface IMyContext
{
    IDbSet<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class UserModel
{
    IMyContext myContext;

    UserModel(IMyContext myContext) 
    {
       this.myContext = myContext;
    }

    UserProfile GetUser(int id)
    {
       return myContext.Users.Where(u => u.id == id);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to test the UserModel code without a running database. I am aware that I can mock the MyContext - but the code myContext.Users.Where ... may involve complex mocking? Have I structured the code wrong? How can I write tests for models without having a test database? Or should I fake the context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Break your code down into core components and you will realize that all you need to do is mock the context's `Users` property. After that, the Where is really just a static method working against an `IEnumerable` object

```
var users = myContext.Users;
var returnEnumerable = Enumerable.Where(users, u=>u.id == id);
return returnEnumerable
```

So, just mock your context in such a way that when `.Users` is called, it returns an `IDbSet<UserProfile>` of your making

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but isnt IDbSet an interface too? So we would have to mock that too?

Comment: You can do that, or you can just have Users return as a concrete implementation of IDbSet